# Pointers to threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc

Suppose i have pointer to a thread like this

```
CWinThread *m_pThread = AfxBeginThread(StartThread, this, THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL, 0, 0);
```

Now in my StartThread function assume i did all operations and the function returned like this

```
UINT CClassThread::StartThread(LPVOID pVoid)
{
     return true;
}
```

Will my m_pThread be invalid when the return statement is executed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it will be invalid because it will be deleted at the end of the thread.  However, if you set `CWinThread::m_bAutoDelete` to `FALSE`, the `CWinThread*` won't be deleted.  I just googled for the answer and found it here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/48xz4yz9(VS.80).aspx

As an aside, if you were using pthreads (Unix threads), the answer would be no.  When a thread terminates, its handle remains valid until you call `pthread_join` (wait for a thread to finish, deallocate it, and get its return value) or `pthread_detach` (tell a thread to deallocate itself when it completes).

Comment: Ok and by being invalid would it be NULL or some data which is not valid.

Comment: It would be a wild pointer (invalid).  C++ won't hunt down your pointers and NULL them out when they become invalid :-)

Comment: `m_pThread` will keep it's value, even though the object it pointed to is deallocated. It will become a [dangling pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer).